# Upload image in imageview inside collectionView using sdwebimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I have to show image in `imageView` using `SDWebImage`

**Here is my code:**

```
NSString *string2 = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]valueForKey:@"logo"];

[imagev sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/upload/post/"]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:string2]
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                             imagev.image = image;
 }];
```

I am not getting any image inside `ImageView`

data I am getting from the server is

```
data array (
        {
        address = brisbane;
        amount = 0;
        "business_phone" = 9990688436;
        catid = 0;
        catname = "";
        city = delhi;
        contactperson = "Gautam Kumar";
        country = Australia;
        createdon = 1464935578;
        email = "gautam.kumar@eyeforweb.com";
        expirydays = 366;
        expirymail = 0;
        "fb_address" = "";
        id = 78;
        "inst_address" = "";
        isexpired = 0;
        isfeatured = 0;
        lat = "-33.7961";
        "link_address" = "";
        lng = "151.146";
        logo = "";
        longdesc = "xyz ";
        mobileno = "";
        officephone = "";
        ondedaysmail = 0;
        "package_name" = 0;
        paidamount1 = 0;
        paydate1 = 0;
        paystatus1 = 1;
        "prod_name" = 13;
        "pt_address" = "";
        sevendaysmail = 0;
        shortdesc = hello123;
        state = "New South Wales";
        status = 1;
        tags = "";
        "tb_address" = "";
        title = aayush;
        transcationid1 = "";
        "tw_address" = "";
        userid = 5;
        username = "Gautam Kumar";
        "var_name" = 56;
        "web_address" = "";
    },
        {
        address = "Address 1";
        amount = 0;
        "business_phone" = 9990688436;
        catid = 0;
        catname = "";
        city = ABD;
        contactperson = "Gautam Kumar";
        country = Australia;
        createdon = 1464158696;
        email = "gautam.kumar@eyeforweb.com";
        expirydays = 357;
        expirymail = 0;
        "fb_address" = "";
        id = 75;
        "inst_address" = "";
        isexpired = 0;
        isfeatured = 0;
        lat = "-37.488";
        "link_address" = "";
        lng = "144.592";
        logo = "appflowchart_4c1.gif";
        longdesc = "This is short Description.";
        mobileno = "";
        officephone = "";
        ondedaysmail = 0;
        "package_name" = 0;
        paidamount1 = 0;
        paydate1 = 0;
        paystatus1 = 1;
        "prod_name" = 3;
        "pt_address" = "";
        sevendaysmail = 0;
        shortdesc = "This is short Description.";
        state = Gisborne;
        status = 1;
        tags = "";
        "tb_address" = "";
        title = Business1;
        transcationid1 = "";
        "tw_address" = "";
        userid = 5;
        username = "Gautam Kumar";
        "var_name" = 0;
        "web_address" = "";
    },
        {
        address = "Paschim Vihar ,Delhi";
        amount = 0;
        "business_phone" = 9990688436;
        catid = 0;
        catname = "";
        city = "New Delhi";
        contactperson = "Gautam Kumar";
        country = Australia;
        createdon = 1464065014;
        email = "gautam.kumar@eyeforweb.com";
        expirydays = 356;
        expirymail = 0;
        "fb_address" = Facebook;
        id = 72;
        "inst_address" = Instagram;
        isexpired = 0;
        isfeatured = 0;
        lat = "-37.488";
        "link_address" = linked;
        lng = "144.592";
        logo = "Screenshot_(1)_61b.png";
        longdesc = sdfsdfdsf;
        mobileno = "";
        officephone = "";
        ondedaysmail = 0;
        "package_name" = 0;
        paidamount1 = 0;
        paydate1 = 0;
        paystatus1 = 1;
        "prod_name" = 3;
        "pt_address" = Pinsta;
        sevendaysmail = 0;
        shortdesc = fffsdf;
        state = Gisborne;
        status = 1;
        tags = "";
        "tb_address" = Tumbler;
        title = "First business";
        transcationid1 = "";
        "tw_address" = Twitter;
        userid = 5;
        username = "Gautam Kumar";
        "var_name" = 2;
        "web_address" = Website;
    },
        {
        address = Laxminagar;
        amount = 0;
        "business_phone" = 9990688436;
        catid = 0;
        catname = "";
        city = "New Delhi1";
        contactperson = "Gautam Kumar";
        country = Australia;
        createdon = 1463651418;
        email = "gautam.kumar@eyeforweb.com";
        expirydays = 7;
        expirymail = 0;
        "fb_address" = Facebook;
        id = 61;
        "inst_address" = Instagram;
        isexpired = 0;
        isfeatured = 0;
        lat = "28.6433";
        "link_address" = linked;
        lng = "77.0363";
        logo = "Screenshot_(1)_0ba.png";
        longdesc = asxasxasx;
        mobileno = "";
        officephone = "";
        ondedaysmail = 0;
        "package_name" = 0;
        paidamount1 = 0;
        paydate1 = 0;
        paystatus1 = 1;
        "prod_name" = 3;
        "pt_address" = Pinsta;
        sevendaysmail = 0;
        shortdesc = xasxasx;
        state = Victoria;
        status = 1;
        tags = "";
        "tb_address" = Tumbler;
        title = "Testing by Gautam";
        transcationid1 = 1111111111111;
        "tw_address" = Twitter;
        userid = 5;
        username = "Gautam Kumar";
        "var_name" = 2;
        "web_address" = Website;
    }
)
```

Comment: What is your development target ???

Comment: I think you need have a  full path to your image in server not just a Screenshot_(1)_61b.png and your NSURL should look like `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/upload/post/Screenshot_(1)_0ba.png"]`

Comment: but there is not only one image there are various images so each cell will show different image @iSashok

Comment: So you can just add your string2 to NSURL like that `[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/up‌​load/post/, string2]]`

Comment: no still not getting any image it is showing error

Comment: error is not coming any but image is not display on imageview? @Bhavin

Comment: how to do this @Bhavin plz tell me

Comment: @AayushKatiyar use `NSString *a = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/up‌​load/post/, string2] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];`  than pass a into your url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aayush Katiyar,

From iOS 8 onwards you are not supposed to use http you should make use of secure channels https. In case you dont have one consider adding these to your plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

All your image download api is making use of http:// I guess that might be the issue here

Finally change the way you load the image as

```
[imagev sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",@"http://dev-demo.info.bh-in-15.webhostbox.net/dv/nationalblack/upload/post/", string2]]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Some_Placeholder_Image"]
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                             imagev.image = image;
 }];
```

Comment: @aayush-katiyar : Have you tried loading image as I have mentioned in my answer ???

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this,

```
 [cell.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:finalImageUrl];
```

`finalImageUrl` is your final `url` for download image.

No need to use method with completion handlerl. it is for different task.

Comment: i am not getting image still in my imageview @lion

Comment: then check your url it is valid or not

Comment: Check your response, somewhere logo's value is `empty string` when somwhere it is `gif` so somewhere it is `png`. try to select png and it should work.